# Aggregate when one of the "by" column-values is NA

Tags: r, aggregate

I have an input dataframe "testdata" like this:

```
valX valY id
 1    2   NA
 4    5   NA
 7    8   1
```

If I do:

```
aggregate(data.frame(testdata$valX, testdata$valY), by = list(id = testdata$id), FUN = mean)
```

I get only the row where the id is not NA.

Does anyone know a way to also apply the aggregate for all rows where the id is NA?

I would like to get some results like this:

```
 valX valY id
 2.5  3.5  NA
  7    8   1
```

Note: I would prefer to have a solution with the basic R package due to some license reasons.

Comment: Did you try replacing `NA` with `"NA"` ?

Comment: Using `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(mean)` will give the correct result.

Comment: @TUSHAr I tried that, but the thing is at the end a string "NA" will be shown to the user, where empty space is prefered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `aggregate` is that it keeps only complete cases in the object passed in the argument `by` and there is no option to disable that.

I would suggest to use either `dplyr` or `data.table`:

the `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

testdata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id  valX  valY
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   7.0   8.0
2    NA   2.5   3.5
```

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(testdata)
testdata[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = id]

   id valX valY
1: NA  2.5  3.5
2:  1  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: I found that actually the data.table package I can use, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, could you add back the modified aggregation function, I would also like to learn how that is done, I think it's quick useful to understand.

Comment: You can use `View(aggregate.data.frame)` copy that code into a new script and change the line `keep <- complete.cases(by)` to `keep <- rep(TRUE, length(by))` and save the function with e.g. `aggregate_w_na <- function()..`

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
aggregate(data.frame(testdata$valX, testdata$valY), 
          by = list(replace(testdata$id, is.na(d$id), "NA")), FUN = mean)
  Group.1 d.valX d.valY
1       1    7.0    8.0
2      NA    2.5    3.5
```

Comment: variant: `aggregate(cbind(valX, valY) ~ replace(id, is.na(id), "NA"), FUN=mean, data=testdata)`